# binding gridview with two listbox asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to bind a single `GridView` with two `ListBox`'s values.
I have successfully bound one list box value in the `GridView` but don't know how to bind both list boxes at same time.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Menu", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    dt.Columns.Add("cost", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (lst.Selected)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["Menu"] = lst.Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

       //GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

also tried this code but it didn't work

```
 DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
    dt1.Columns.Add("Menu", Type.GetType("System.String"));
  //dt1.Columns.Add("cost", Type.GetType("System.String"));
    foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (lst.Selected)
        {
            DataRow dr1 = dt1.NewRow();
            dr1["Menu"] = lst.Text;
            String strQuery = "SELECT cost FROM menu where name = '" + ListBox1.SelectedValue + "'";
           // dr1["Cost"] = lst.Value;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt1);
            dt1.Rows.Add(dr1);
        }

        GridView2.DataSource = dt1;
        GridView2.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code you've written already and explain why it didn't work. If you've done the process once, why is doing it a second time not working?

Comment: added the code above

Answer (score 0):

something like this will work ,

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Menu", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dt.Columns.Add("cost", Type.GetType("System.String"));

        // capture selected item value for 1st listbox 
        foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (lst.Selected)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Menu"] = lst.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

        }

        // capture selected item value for 2nd listbox 
        foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox2.Items)
        {
            if (lst.Selected)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr["Menu"] = lst.Text;
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }


        }

        // finally display the data to gridview 
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();


    }
```

you original code create logic to capture value only when listbox item was selected , so make sure you select both listbox item then you will able capture 2 row on your data table.
[image]